# Problemas com acesso do Pouchdb

Tags: rest, pouchdb

Uso do PouchDB com um REST API para fazer um replicate.to? 
É seguinte, sigo o exemplo simples do PouchDB:

```
bancolocal = new PouchDB('http://192.168.1.100:5984/bancoexterno');
```

O problema está quando rodo a aplicação, percebi pelo crhome inspect que ele retorna uma URL do tipo `http://192.168.1.100:5984/bancoexterno/`  acrescentando um `“/”` no final do endereço , direcionando para um diretório não para um serviço RESP, e assim não localizando o DB e apresentado um:

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Versão do ionic 2.0.0-beta.31

O banco de dados é o SQLite3

Obs.: O Resp está perfeito, no browser responde corretamente com o banco de dados assim como no crhome Advanced REST client.

Comment: Não acho que a barra no final comprometa a requisição. Utilizando o comando curl to terminal para chamar a tua url do get funciona?

Comment: Giuliana obrigado por responder.
No momento desisti de fazer esta requisição, Mas breve tentarei (apenas para teste) e posto o resultado com o curl e posto o resultado.

Comment: Tá certo, mas tente mesmo! Em breve é eufemismo pra nunca... kkkk. Precisando de ajuda é só falar ;)

Comment: "Em breve é eufemismo pra nunca..." Gostei disso. 
Pode deixar precisando de ajuda vou pedir mesmo, e olha que sou iniciante.